# Null check operator used on a null value when connecting API's in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I've been having this problem when trying to connect API's in flutter. I'm not sure if this is a problem of not receiving the data or if there is an error in my code, any hekp would be greatly appreciated.

#### This is the code I have on the page

```
import 'package:ctrade/models/newsinfo.dart';
import 'package:ctrade/services/api_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PostsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostsPage({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PostsPage> createState() => _PostsPageState();
}


class _PostsPageState extends State<PostsPage> {
 late Future<Welcome> _Welcome; //error here


  @override
  void initState() {
    _Welcome = API_Manager().getNews();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold (
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('News App'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<Welcome>(
          future: _Welcome,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 52,
                itemBuilder:(context, index) {
                var ticker = snapshot.data!.ticker[index];
              return Container(
                height: 100,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    //Text(ticker)
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
            } 
            else 
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
          
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

#### This is the code on my API manager file (I defined the news_url in a different file)

```
import 'package:ctrade/constants/strings.dart';
import 'package:ctrade/models/newsinfo.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class API_Manager {

  Future<Welcome> getNews() async{
    var client = http.Client();
    var Welcome;


try{
    var response = await client.get(Uri.parse(Strings.news_url));
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonString = response.body;
      var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
      
      
      Welcome = Welcome.fromJson(jsonMap);
    }

}
catch(Exception)
{
  return Welcome;
}
    return Welcome;
  }
}
```

### This is the file with the parsed json

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final welcome = welcomeFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<Welcome> welcomeFromJson(String str) => List<Welcome>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Welcome.fromJson(x)));

String welcomeToJson(List<Welcome> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Welcome {
    Welcome({
        required this.id,
        required this.ticker,
        required this.isin,
        required this.bestAsk,
        required this.bestBid,
        required this.currentPrice,
        required this.askVolume,
        required this.bidVolume,
        required this.fullCompanyName,
        required this.prevPrice,
        required this.prevPer,
        required this.prevChange,
    });

    int id;
    String ticker;
    String isin;
    String bestAsk;
    String bestBid;
    String currentPrice;
    String askVolume;
    String bidVolume;
    String fullCompanyName;
    String prevPrice;
    String prevPer;
    String prevChange;

    factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
        id: json["id"],
        ticker: json["Ticker"],
        isin: json["ISIN"],
        bestAsk: json["Best_Ask"],
        bestBid: json["Best_bid"],
        currentPrice: json["Current_price"],
        askVolume: json["Ask_Volume"],
        bidVolume: json["Bid_Volume"],
        fullCompanyName: json["FullCompanyName"],
        prevPrice: json["PrevPrice"],
        prevPer: json["PrevPer"],
        prevChange: json["PrevChange"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "Ticker": ticker,
        "ISIN": isin,
        "Best_Ask": bestAsk,
        "Best_bid": bestBid,
        "Current_price": currentPrice,
        "Ask_Volume": askVolume,
        "Bid_Volume": bidVolume,
        "FullCompanyName": fullCompanyName,
        "PrevPrice": prevPrice,
        "PrevPer": prevPer,
        "PrevChange": prevChange,
    };
}
```

Comment: any Error show?

Comment: Yeah when I hot reload/restart it gives an error saying 'Null check operator used on a null value'

Comment: Add a language version comment to the top of any Dart files that you don’t want to consider during your current migration: `// @dart=2.9`

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Welcome {
  Welcome({
  required this.id,
  required this.ticker,
  required this.isin,
  required this.bestAsk,
  required this.bestBid,
  required this.currentPrice,
  required this.askVolume,
  required this.bidVolume,
  required this.fullCompanyName,
  required this.prevPrice,
  required this.prevPer,
  required this.prevChange,
  });

  int? id;
  String? ticker;
  String? isin;
  String? bestAsk;
  String? bestBid;
  String? currentPrice;
  String? askVolume;
  String? bidVolume;
  String? fullCompanyName;
  String? prevPrice;
  String? prevPer;
  String? prevChange;

  factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
  id: json["id"]??"",
  ticker: json["Ticker"]??"",
  isin: json["ISIN"]??"",
  bestAsk: json["Best_Ask"]??"",
  bestBid: json["Best_bid"]??"",
  currentPrice: json["Current_price"]??"",
  askVolume: json["Ask_Volume"]??"",
  bidVolume: json["Bid_Volume"]??"",
  fullCompanyName: json["FullCompanyName"]??"",
  prevPrice: json["PrevPrice"]??"",
  prevPer: json["PrevPer"]??"",
  prevChange: json["PrevChange"]??"",
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
  "id": id,
  "Ticker": ticker,
  "ISIN": isin,
  "Best_Ask": bestAsk,
  "Best_bid": bestBid,
  "Current_price": currentPrice,
  "Ask_Volume": askVolume,
  "Bid_Volume": bidVolume,
  "FullCompanyName": fullCompanyName,
  "PrevPrice": prevPrice,
  "PrevPer": prevPer,
  "PrevChange": prevChange,
  };
  }
```

Comment: I tried this and it's still giving me the same error

Comment: Please show me your error

Comment: Whenever I hot reload/restart the error comes up on the emulator saying 'Null check operator used on a null value'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: import 'package:ctrade/constants/strings.dart';